# Returning raw address from pandas column using Geopy?

Tags: python, google-maps-api, pandas, geopy

I have a Pandas dataframe, and I'm calling a geopy function on each row of 'address_original' column to get as much detail as possible about every address

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key='', timeout=5, 
                      )

df['full_address_geocoded'] = df['address_original'].progress_apply(geolocator.geocode())
print df['full_address_geocoded'][:5]

0    (Veale Rd, New Plymouth, New Zealand, (-39.095...
1    (Veale Rd, Delaware, USA, (39.8036422, -75.494...
2    (1068 Clearwater Valley Rd, Clearwater, BC V0E...
3    (1605 Pine St W, Stillwater, MN 55082, USA, (4...
4                                                 None
```

The issue is that I need more information than there is included when using geocode method. Geopy also has .raw function, which works perfectly on a single string and outputs the data about what region the address belong to, area, etc.

```
places = '1238 Davie St, Vancouver, BC'


geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key='AIzaSyBlNIvZTk-BpWDeX1FFXPbx6QwbNzZL80w')
location = geolocator.geocode(places, language='en')
print location.raw

{u'geometry': {u'location_type': u'ROOFTOP', u'bounds': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 50.6539919, u'lng': -120.3383232}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 50.6538198, u'lng': -120.3386968}}, u'viewport': {u'northeast': {u'lat': 50.6552548302915, u'lng': -120.3371610197085}, u'southwest': {u'lat': 50.6525568697085, u'lng': -120.3398589802915}}, u'location': {u'lat': 50.6539239, u'lng': -120.3385242}}, u'address_components': [{u'long_name': u'142', u'types': [u'street_number'], u'short_name': u'142'}, {u'long_name': u'Waddington Drive', u'types': [u'route'], u'short_name': u'Waddington Dr'}, {u'long_name': u'Upper Sahali', u'types': [u'neighborhood', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Upper Sahali'}, {u'long_name': u'Kamloops', u'types': [u'locality', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Kamloops'}, {u'long_name': u'Thompson-Nicola', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_2', u'political'], u'short_name': u'Thompson-Nicola'}, {u'long_name': u'British Columbia', u'types': [u'administrative_area_level_1', u'political'], u'short_name': u'BC'}, {u'long_name': u'Canada', u'types': [u'country', u'political'], u'short_name': u'CA'}, {u'long_name': u'V2E 1N3', u'types': [u'postal_code'], u'short_name': u'V2E 1N3'}], u'place_id': u'ChIJaV6wtDgsflMR1J9ReM0lzLs', u'formatted_address': u'142 Waddington Dr, Kamloops, BC V2E 1N3, Canada', u'types': [u'premise']}
```

The raw method doesn't work on multiple values, however, I get the TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable.

What is a way around this?

Comment: Please show the code that produce the error message

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3

adresslist = r'https://gist.githubusercontent.com/HeroicEric/1102788/raw/0bcb298bd75513a398bf353ce7162177350813c9/gistfile1.txt'
df = pd.read_csv(adresslist, names=['firstpart','secondpart'])
df['adress_original'] = df['firstpart']+df['secondpart']

geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key='AIzaSyBlNIvZTk-BpWDeX1FFXPbx6QwbNzZL80w')
df['adress_original'].head(5).apply(lambda x: geolocator.geocode(x, language='en').raw)

0    {'address_components': [{'long_name': '777', '...
1    {'address_components': [{'long_name': '30', 's...
2    {'address_components': [{'long_name': '250', '...
3    {'address_components': [{'long_name': '700', '...
4    {'address_components': [{'long_name': '66', 's...
```